# Show http requests (counter) as a table in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, counter, grafana, promql

I have an extremely simple Prometheus metrics collected by my API.

It's called `http_server_requests` and comes with three labels:

- method
- status_code
- route

My API is a k8s deployment with 3 replicas.

First of all, I don't understand why the counter values are not consistent with each other.

**Last hour (fine! we don't have any errors)**

[image]

**Last 2 hours (oh! we had an error)**

[image]

**Last 5 hours (more errors, they are counted. nice)**

[image]

**Last 8 hours.... wait. WTF?! FEWER errors? How is that even possible?**

[image]

---

The second part of the question is about Grafana.

I tried to visualize the "last 5 hours" above data in a table panel. But the values displayed aren't consistent w/ Prometheus!

[image]

[image]

What's the best configuration to show counters in a table in Grafana?